# How to disable default HTML input validation message?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I press the submit button for an empty HTML text input, this default message automatically appears. I want the border of the box to become red instead of this default message appearing. How do I do it?

Here's the code for the box:

```html
<div class="input-group" id="email-input">
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" required placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot showing the default message]

Comment: "Inline validation" is the term for this. There are plenty of tutorials and libraries, if you want to find something already existent instead of waiting for a proper answer here. The basic technique is to either listen for events on the individual inputs and validate them in the event callbacks (eager validation) or listen for the submit event, validate all the inputs at once, and prevent the submit if any are invalid.

Comment: Re UX design: [A Complete Guide To Live Validation UX | Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2022/09/inline-validation-web-forms-ux/); [Inline validation in forms — designing the experience | Medium](https://medium.com/wdstack/inline-validation-in-forms-designing-the-experience-123fb34088ce); [Inline form validations — UX design considerations and React examples | Medium](https://medium.com/@shanplourde/inline-form-validations-ux-design-considerations-and-react-examples-c2f53f89bebc)

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using JavaScript, there is a event called invalid that fires on every error. We will use that event and check by regex if text is proper email or not. We will create a function for this.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<input type="email" id="input" required>
```

JavaScript

```
const input = document.querySelector('#input');
  
function validation(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('invalid', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (elem.value === '') {
            alert("Fill Your Email");
        } else if (!/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(elem.value)) {
            alert('Invalid Email');
        } 
    });
}

validation(input);
```

Note : This currently only supports validation of Email inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of bootstrap you are using but [bootstrap v5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/) probably has what you are looking for.

Import bootstrap v5.0 before title tag in html file:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

then try this:

```
<form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="validationCustom01" class="form-label">First name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" value="Mark" required>
    <div class="valid-feedback"> Looks good! </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="validationCustom02" class="form-label">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide a valid Last name.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">Agree to terms and conditions</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">You must agree before submitting.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
  </div>
</form>
```